# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base [...] does not exist or is not a readable directory

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

i start with Servlet i instal Tomcat 7,

And this is console when i start tomcat in eclipse:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Users\Janko\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\Servlet does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5055)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you run tomcat inside your Eclipse IDE, 
There are few common steps to overcome 404.

1. Open the "server tab" in Eclipse. (Window Menu => Show view => Other = > Server.(Type Server in the popup box if you could not find)
2. Click "New Server" Wizard" add tomcat.
3. Right Click on tomcat server instance.Click on properties

[image]4. Then you see the properties. Click on 'Location' property. Click Switch Location. (By default this value is workspace metadata by switching location you give location of your tomcat you refer)

[image]5.Click on "Tomcat7 Server" and make sure you have selected "Use  Tomcat installation (take controls from Tomcat installation)

Comment: HI, thank you i add new server i setings server location as "Use Tomcat installation" but when i start my simple servlet i still have 404 status. What can be wrong with it?